# How to map the value of a h:selectBooleanCheckbox in a ui:repeat with in ui:repeat

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, hashmap, jsf-1.2

Please help me how to map the value in `h:selectBooleanCheckbox` in a `ui:repeat` within a `ui:repeat`

I have tried the below code but selected values not populated in javabean

bean:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> getSelectedAttributeValues() {
      return selectedAttributeValues;
}

public void setSelectedAttributeValues(Map<String, Map<String, Boolean>> selectedAttributeValues) {
    this.selectedAttributeValues = selectedAttributeValues;
}
```

xhtml:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{productListForm.catalogueAttributeNames}" var="catAttrName">
    <h3 class="section inset-dark"><h:outputText value="#{catAttrName}"/><span class="right"></span></h3>
            <div class="drop-down-container">
                <ul class="filter-list">
                    <ui:repeat value="#{productListForm.catalogueResultBean.catalogueAttributes[catAttrName]}" var="productAttr">
                        <li class="filter-list-item">
                            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectedAttr" value="#{productListForm.selectedAttributeValues[catAttrName][productAttr.value]}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="selectedAttr">
                                <h:outputText value="#{productAttr.valueDisplay}"/>
                            </h:outputLabel>
                        </li>
                    </ui:repeat>

                    <li class="filter-list-item">
                        <h:commandLink styleClass="product_search_update_link" action="#{productListForm.filterAction}">
                            <h:outputText  value="#{text['productSearch.result.updateResult']}"/>
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
     </ui:repeat>
```

After selecting a check box java bean had empty hashmap and there is no values with boolean flag.
what is wrong in the above code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Tagged [jsf-2] and [jsf-1.2] simultaneously. Make it reflect the correct version which you are interested in.

Comment: Are you trying to `put` to the map from the checkbox? I don't think that's supported. You can definitely `get`